# Definition of Convergence of a Sequence and Series Questions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

I am struggling to understand what Question 1 and 2 are [(In the Assignment)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWgzV.png)  asking for and I cannot make a move to start off. For Question 2, I do not know how to get a j by itself after trying to minus 1/3 from aj. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1: Let $(X_n)$ be a convergent sequence in $A_{X_0,N}$ with limit $X$.

Then we have $<N,X_n-X_0> \le 0$  for all $n$. The continuity of the inner product then gives $<N,X-X_0> \le 0$, hence  $X \in A_{X_0,N}$.

Question 2 ,1):

Show that $|a_j-\frac{1}{3}|=\frac{8}{9j^2+3j} \le \frac{8}{9j^2}  \le \frac{1}{j^2}  \le \frac{1}{j} $.

Can you proceed ?

Comment: Thanks, an edit will follow ...

Comment: Thanks, although I do not understand question 4 though.